Page transitions depend on route (Next.js 14 & Framer Motion)
In my app, I've implemented a tab-styled navigation bar to facilitate navigation between different categories of places, each with its own route. I've successfully applied page transitions between these routes using the code below in a nested layout file.

However, I'm encountering two specific issues:

Transition Animation and Modals: When a user clicks on an item, it's
navigated to a different route presented as a modal with the help of
Parallel Routes. I'm facing challenges with the page transition
animation still running behind the modal when it's opened or closed.
While I've managed to prevent this partially, there's still some
overlap occurring.

Transition Direction based on Tab Position: Additionally, I want the
transition direction to be determined by the tab's position in the
navigation bar. For example, if a user clicks on a tab to the right
of the current one, I'd like the animation to move from left to
right.


I attempted to utilize the useParams() hook for obtaining the current route. Then, with each change, I aimed to store the previous version using useRef(). If neither the previous nor the current path contains the place property, I intended to increment another counter, keyCounter, initialized with useRef(0), which serves as the key for the motion element. However, despite my attempts, I couldn't get it to work as expected.
const FrozenRouter = (props: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const context = useContext(LayoutRouterContext);
  const frozen = useRef(context).current;
  return <LayoutRouterContext.Provider value={frozen}>{props.children}</LayoutRouterContext.Provider>;
};

const Layout = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const paramsBeforeChange = useRef<Params>({});
  const keyCounter = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { city: cityBeforeChange, category: categoryBeforeChange, place: placeBeforeChange } = paramsBeforeChange.current;
    const { city: cityAfterChange, category: categoryAfterChange, place: placeAfterChange } = params;

    if (placeBeforeChange !== undefined || placeAfterChange !== undefined) {
      console.log("shouldn't animate");
      return;
    }

    keyCounter.current++;
    paramsBeforeChange.current = params;
  }, [params]);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <AnimatePresence mode="popLayout" initial={false}>
        <motion.main
          key={keyCounter.current}
          className="h-screen overflow-y-scroll pb-8 pt-28"
          initial={{ opacity: 1, x: "-100%" }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 1, x: "100%" }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.6, ease: "easeInOut" }}
        >
          <FrozenRouter>{children}</FrozenRouter>
        </motion.main>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};


it would be better if you could create a reusable repo. right now, everything seems very abstract

 I'm facing challenges with the page transition animation still running behind the modal when it's opened or closed. . what is the desired behaviour?

Handling transition animations and modals in React can sometimes be tricky, especially when dealing with nested routes and transitions between them. Let's break down your two issues and see how we can approach them:
Transition Animation and Modals
To prevent the transition animation from running behind the modal when it's opened or closed, you can conditionally apply the animation based on the presence of the modal. Here's an example of how you might adjust your code:
import { useState } from 'react';

const Layout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  // Function to handle opening and closing of the modal
  const handleModalToggle = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(!isModalOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <AnimatePresence>
        {/* Conditionally apply animation based on modal state */}
        {isModalOpen ? (
          <ModalComponent onClose={handleModalToggle} />
        ) : (
          <motion.main
            className="h-screen overflow-y-scroll pb-8 pt-28"
            initial={{ opacity: 0, x: '-100%' }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, x: '100%' }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.6, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
          >
            {children}
          </motion.main>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;

In this code:

We use the isModalOpen state to track whether the modal is open or closed.
Depending on the isModalOpen state, we conditionally render either the modal component or the main content with the desired animation.
The ModalComponent is a placeholder for your actual modal component, and handleModalToggle is a function to toggle the modal state.

Transition Direction based on Tab Position
For determining the transition direction based on the tab's position in the navigation bar, you can consider using a custom hook or context to manage the navigation state. Here's a simplified example:
import { useState } from 'react';

// Custom hook to manage navigation state
const useNavigation = () => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState<string>('');

  const handleTabChange = (tab: string) => {
    // Determine transition direction based on tab position
    // For example, you can compare tab indices or names
    // and set a transition direction accordingly

    setSelectedTab(tab);
  };

  return { selectedTab, handleTabChange };
};

const Layout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { selectedTab, handleTabChange } = useNavigation();

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar onTabChange={handleTabChange} />
      <AnimatePresence>
        {/* Conditionally apply animation based on selected tab */}
        {selectedTab === 'SomeTabName' ? (
          <motion.main
            className="h-screen overflow-y-scroll pb-8 pt-28"
            initial={{ opacity: 0, x: '-100%' }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, x: '100%' }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.6, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
          >
            {children}
          </motion.main>
        ) : (
          <OtherComponent />
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;

In this code:

We use the useNavigation custom hook to manage the selected tab state and handle tab changes.
Depending on the selected tab, we conditionally apply different animations or render different components.
You can customize the handleTabChange function to determine the transition direction based on your specific requirements.

